# Extend precision of MySQL's double datatype?

Tags: mysql, types

I am trying to save the value "6.714285714285714" into a DOUBLE datatype field.
Unfortunately, it does not fit at all and is trimmed by one digit. Storing larger numbers becomes less precise.

I have already searched in the mysql manual and it seems to be that double is the most precise data type available. Does anyone know a practical workaround?

Answer (score 2):

DECIMAL is a better choice than DOUBLE if you need precision.